# Using pointers, overridden method not being called

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, polymorphism

I am using a vector of pointers to `Primitive`s:

```
vector<Primitive*> primitives;
```

In which I put a pointer to a class derived from `Primitive`, namely `Instance`:

```
Shape * s = new Sphere();
PhongMaterial* mat = new PhongMaterial(this, 0.6, 0.15, 0.2, Color(1, 0, 0), 50);
Instance* redSphere = new Instance(s, mat);
redSphere->scale(1, 10, 1);
primitives.push_back(redSphere);
```

This is `Instance.h`:

```
class Instance: public Primitive {
private:
Transform* invTransform;
public:
Instance(Shape * const s, Material* const mat);

bool intersect(const Ray& ray, float& tmin, Intersection& isct);

bool shadow_hit(const Ray& ray, float& tmin);

void scale(float a, float b, float c);

~Instance() {
    ;
}
};
```

And this is `Primitive.h`:

```
class Primitive {
private:
Shape* shape;
Material* material;

public:
Primitive(Shape * const s, Material* const mat);

bool intersect(const Ray& ray, float& tmin, Intersection& isct);

bool shadow_hit(const Ray& ray, float& tmin);

~Primitive() {
    ;
}
};
```

This is the way I'm using it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < primitives.size(); i++) {
    float t;
    if (primitives[i]->intersect(ray, t, iTmp) && t < tMin) {
        tMin = t;
        isect = iTmp;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the loop never calls the `Instance` `intersect()` method. Instead, it calls the method from `Primitive`. I just don't know how object slicing could be happening in this case, as I'm using pointers everywhere.

Eclipse tells me that `Instance`'s `intersect()` method *shadows* the method from `Primitive`. Does that have to do with anything? I'm new to C++, coming from Java. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Non-virtual methods do not dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only override a function if it's virtual:

```
virtual bool intersect(const Ray& ray, float& tmin, Intersection& isct);
^^^^^^^
```